# How to create an orthogonal matrix in Matlab with one fixed column

Tags: matlab, matrix, orthogonal

I want to create a square NxN matrix orthogonal, with the constraint that the first column is a column vector of k*ones(N,1), where k is a constant at choice. Is there any procedure?

I.e.

```
A= [k * *;k * *;k * *]
```

is a 3x3 matrix, where the first column is a vector k*ones(3,1), and the other two vectors have to be created in such a way the matrix is orthogonal

Comment: Could you please provide a small example of what you mean (input and output)?

Comment: I have edited the question: input the first column vector, output the resulting orthogonal matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this should be posted on [Math.StackEchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) where equations can be typed properly if you want a proper theoretical explanation. But if just want the code...

First, if `N` is the dimension of your matrix, this constrains the value of `k` to:

```
k=sqrt(1/N);
A(1,:) = k*ones(1,N);
```

Then, the second row can be constructed with:

```
A(2,:) = sqrt(0.5)*[1,-1,zeros(1,N-2)];
```

This creates a simple vector orthogonal to the first.

The third line can be computed with:

```
aux = [1,1,-2,zeros(1,N-3)];
A(3,:) = aux/norm(aux);
```

The fourth:

```
aux = [1,1,1,-3,zeros(1,N-4)];
A(4,:) = aux/norm(aux);
```

And so on.

In short:

```
A=zeros(N);
k=sqrt(1/N);
A(1,:) = k*ones(1,N);
for i=2:N
    aux = [ones(1,i-1),-(i-1),zeros(1,N-i)];
    A(i,:) = aux/norm(aux);
end
```

Comment: This is a right one solution. Thanks! This procedure has a name or is an empirical one?

Comment: I'm not aware of a name or a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
kk = k*ones(3,1); % fixed first column (could be anything)
X = [kk, null(kk')']
```

gives you a square matrix with **mutually orthogonal columns**, no matter what's the vector `kk`. It will be an **orthonormal** matrix only when `norm(k)==1` (which implies `k=1/sqrt(3)` in your examples, as the others have noted). Note that the first case does not imply its rows are orthogonal, whereas the second one does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't quote MATLAB code, but I'm sure this will be straightforward to code.

What you want is a [Householder reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation)
These are othonormal matrices that are symmetric (and so are their own inverses). 
Given a vector v you can find a reflector H so that

```
H*v = a*e1
```

where a is += length of v and e1 is (1,0,..)'

I'd imagine MATLAB has a routine for this.

Given the properties of H this means that the first column of H is parallel to v, and the other columns are orthogonal to v and to each other.

So if you scale the first column of H (it is of length 1) appropriately, you have your desired matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a valid solution for the problem! :)